# How do I tell what version of IIS and Windows my Azure App Service is running on

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I received an email from the Azure team that they were planning on upgrading the OS of Azure App Service to Windows 2016.  The only advice they gave was to try running on windows ten or Windows Server 2016 in preparation.

My application started crashing in a new and unexpected way that might be explained by the OS being upgraded, but I would like to verify that it was in fact upgraded before pursuing anything further.

I don't see an upgrade event in the logs and I can't seem to see any operating system version in the portal.  Is there somewhere else I should be looking?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the OS that your App Service is running on by looking at the OS Name field in the Overview blade. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/63#issuecomment-348529295) for more details and a screenshot of what that looks like. Then the IIS version just falls out of that (8.0 for Server 2012 and 10.0 for 2016).

If in fact it got moved to 2016 and you think that's the issue (not super likely as the upgrade barely started), please share the App Service name (either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)) and give more details on how it's crashing. This should not happen and we need to investigate further.

Comment: I have been upgraded to Windows Server 2016.  I am reasonably sure that this caused my site to go down.  My app service name is m4d.azurewebistes.net but I've worked around the issue so it would only be logs from about Saturday 12/9/17 @4pm to Sunday 12/10/19 @ noon (PST) that would be helpful.  The issue was with https://www.nuget.org/packages/JavaScriptEngineSwitcher.Msie to do less compilation.  I can get you more details if that would help.

Comment: Yes, it would be great to have more details. Note that in addition to 2016, it move from 4.7 to 4.7.1, which could conceivably be related. If you are able to come up with a small repro that shows it being broken in 2016 and working on 2012 that would be very helpful (e.g. via a GitHub repo). And also how you fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: @DavidWGray a repro would be very helpful. Also is your app running .net full framework or .net core?

Comment: @ahneksated I'll see if I can find the time to build a repro.  In the meantime I did a quick outline of what I went through here:  http://gramamoto.com/working-bootstrap-less-azure/ - I believe if you create a website and use BundleTransformer and JSEngineSwitcher.MSIE to compile a bootstrap 3 theme you'll stand a decent chance of reproducing the problem - links to all of the parts I used are included in the post.

Comment: thanks @DavidWGray I was able to get a repro running the sample project from https://github.com/Taritsyn/BundleTransformer

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but currently, as at 14-APR-2022, one way is to go to your App Service, then to the App Service Plan, then look at the Operating System in the plan's Overview blade:

[image]

App Service Plan Overview blade:

[image]

Comment: Yes, but what version of Windows is this? I assume it actually means Windows Server Core which limits compatibility - you only get two choices when creating the App Service Plan: Linux and Windows